# Input Values are not going to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-binding, insert

I'm super new to PHP mysql database, can someone help me out how can I make my input appear on the database. This is just a sample I'm testing. I don't know what I'm doing wrong I have all the information from the server inputed it at the right place. I'm getting a messages that it was successful but nothing is going to my database. I have one file called connect.php where the php is and the index.php for the html, table is name cultivar_db. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: Im connecting to my real server.

Structure

1 cultivar_idPrimary int(11) No None AUTO_INCREMENT

2 cultivar_name varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci No None

Heres the complete details in the database

[image]

```js
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "myusername";
    $password = "*****";
    $dbname = "mydbname";
      $cultivar_name = $_POST['cultivar_name'];
    //Database Connection

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die('Connection Failed : ' . $conn->connect_error);
    }else{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cultivar_db(cultivar_name)
            values(?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $cultivar_name);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "successfully input datas..";
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <form action="connect.php" method="post">
    <label>Cultivar Name:</label>
    <input class="inputstyle" type="text" name="cultivar_name"><br />
    <input class="button inputstyle" type="submit" value="import" >
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: please add the table structure.

Comment: @Faesal cultivar_id type: int auto increment cultivar_name: varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 0):

Three possible issues within

```php
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cultivar_db(cuttivar_id, cultivar_name) values(?,?,)");
```

1. The second `,` within the `values` might causes some trouble
2. Your ID field is set to `AUTO INCREMENT`, therefor no reason to insert it
3. You typed `cuttivar_id` in your SQL, instead of `cultivar_id`

If you created your table like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE cultivar_db (
     cultivar_id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     cultivar_name VARCHAR(20),
     PRIMARY KEY (cultivar_id)
);
```

Then all you need for the insert is

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cultivar_db(cultivar_name)
values(?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $cultivar_name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: let me try this and ill see if this will work. Thanks

Comment: It says successfully input data but I cant find it in my database.. on the 2nd one you were saying auto increment so i should just remove it? which one I should remove specifically

Comment: when you name your table like this name_data_db is that gonna be an issue just curious super noob here really.

Comment: Your DB table is setup as `AUTO INCREMENT`, therefor there is no need to create a new record with `cultivar_id` in your INSERT statement unless you need that field for something else. In that case I would add another column for this field and leave the current one alone.

Comment: I remove it from the php. now im getting this. "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0004 seconds.)". What is that mean?

Comment: ,, seems like it didn't work :( Thanks

Comment: It didnt work. Still says successfully imported but nothing is going on. Am i missing something on my html??

Comment: Maybe place a `var_dump($cultivar_name)` after you assign it to see what the actual value is.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param('s', var_dump$cultivar_name); you mena like this??

Comment: More like `$cultivar_name = $_POST['cultivar_name']; var_dump($cultivar_name);`

Comment: it says NULL Successfully input datas..??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244475/discussion-between-crystal-and-guido-faecke).

Comment: if the value is `NULL`, it's not making it back to PHP. Change the `var_dump($cultivar_name);` to `var_dump($_POST)`. If that doesn't show anything, then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: lets go to the chat room so we can chat more there. im trying this now. look at the link above to teh chat room. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your "cultivar_id" is auto-increment, you do not need to add that id from the HTML. You can simply pass the "cultivar_name" from HTML using $_POST.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cultivar_db(cultivar_name) values(?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['cultivar_name']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: tried it, it didnt work any other suggestion?

Comment: Have you checked your database connection? Is it working well?

Comment: It is connecting. If i assigned null on the name everytime i input and submt it i can see null on the database. so it is connecting.

Comment: Any idea you might come up im open on anythign really.

Answer (score 0):

ok I'm a little late; but I hope to be still opportune; I won't add anything regarding syntax errors that other users have already told you to fix;

In my case I will leave you a working example of a database connection system and insert, each property and method has its PHPDOCS where a detailed explanation of the purpose or responsibility of the method is added; You will also notice that I have implemented the getter and setter of each private property:

db.php (file class)

```php
<?php

class HandlerDataBase
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * store the host server point
     */
    private string $host;

    /**
     * @var string
     * store database name
     */
    private string $db;

    /**
     * @var string
     * store the port connection point
     */
    private string $port;

    /**
     * @var string
     * store de username to implement in the connection to db server
     */
    private string $user;

    /**
     * @var string
     * password
     */
    private string $password;

    /**
     * @param  array  $config
     * @return void
     * this method is implement to set the configuration to the database connection
     */
    public function setConfigConnection(array $config)
    {
        foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
            switch ($key) {
                case 'host':
                    $this->setHost($value);
                    break;
                case 'db':
                    $this->setDb($value);
                    break;
                case 'port':
                    $this->setPort($value);
                    break;
                case 'user':
                    $this->setUser($value);
                    break;
                case 'password':
                    $this->setPassword($value);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHost(): string
    {
        return $this->host;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string  $host
     */
    public function setHost(string $host): void
    {
        $this->host = $host;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDb(): string
    {
        return $this->db;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string  $db
     */
    public function setDb(string $db): void
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPort(): string
    {
        return $this->port;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string  $port
     */
    public function setPort(string $port): void
    {
        $this->port = $port;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUser(): string
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string  $user
     */
    public function setUser(string $user): void
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string  $password
     */
    public function setPassword(string $password): void
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string  $query
     * @param $value
     * @return void
     * this method implements a connection and executes the query script and the value passed.
     * if there is an error it will be displayed, and execution will be stopped.
     */
    public function setData(string $query, $value)
    {
        try {
            $conn = $this->getConnection();
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $conn->beginTransaction();
            $conn->exec("set names utf8");
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $value);
            $stmt->execute();
            $conn->commit();
            $conn->close();
        } catch (PDOException|Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e);
        }

    }

    /**
     * @return PDO
     * this method create a connection to the db
     */
    private function getConnection(): PDO
    {
        return new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->getDb().";port=".$this->getPort()." dbname=".$this->getDb(), $this->getUser(), $this->getPassword());
    }
}
```

implementation:

```php
<?php
require_once 'db.php';

$config = [
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'db'   => 'my_db_name',
    'port' => '3306',
    'user' => 'my_username',
    'pass' => '********',
];

if (!isset($_POST['cultivar_name']) || '' != $_POST['cultivar_name']) {
    echo 'Error: not received cultivar name data';
    exit();
}

$cultivar_name = $_POST['cultivar_name'];
$query = "INSERT INTO cultivar_db(cultivar_name) values(?)";

$handler_database = new HandlerDataBase();
$handler_database->setConfigConnection($config);
$handler_database->setData($query, $cultivar_name);
```

another way to handle the configuration to the connection to the database, can be with a specific external file, see this:

config.php

```php
<?php
$config = [
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'db'   => 'my_db_name',
    'port' => '3306',
    'user' => 'my_username',
    'pass' => '********',
];
```

then your implementation would look like this:

```php
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'db.php';

if (!isset($_POST['cultivar_name']) || '' != $_POST['cultivar_name']) {
    echo 'Error: not received cultivar name data';
    exit();
}

$cultivar_name = $_POST['cultivar_name'];
$query = "INSERT INTO cultivar_db(cultivar_name) values(?)";

$handler_database = new HandlerDataBase();
$handler_database->setConfigConnection($config);
$handler_database->setData($query, $cultivar_name);
```

Comment: I will try this today. so far I got to the point that if i put null on cultivar_name successfully im getting the NULL  into the datbase  row. any ideas? you said catch to catch i was looking that up.

Comment: if the input comes from a form, you shouldn't be able to insert a null, actually you're trying to insert an empty value, which is valid, but you can control it and avoid it, I'll add it to the code.

Comment: i assigned the cultivar_name as null and then when i input name its numll on the row it means connection is fine and right but values are not inputing right.

Comment: @Crystal implementing security is another matter; that was not the reason for your initial question; I would recommend taking that question and the actual content of your script to codereview.

Comment: I have that figured out i think all the login and password stuff is already set on my files all i want is after implementing the login and password input the values to the datbase.. I will try your codeand Ill chat you in the chat room. Thank you so much I really appreciate all the efforts

Comment: no reason; what I have passed you is an object oriented script, I hope you study it and you can implement it is much safer than the one you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244515/discussion-between-crystal-and-arcanisgk507).